# "Login timeout expired" error when accessing MS SQL db via sqlalchemy and pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sqlcmd

So I have some trouble getting sqlalchemy and pyodbc working with a remote MS SQL Server. Local sqlcmd worked properly but not when I try to read the db via python code. Any help would be appreciated.

Environment:

- Centos 7
- SQLCmd version: Version 17.1.0000.1 Linux
- MS SQL Server 6.01.7601.17514
- Python 2.7

The following sqlcmd worked properly

```
sqlcmd -S {Host},{Port} -U {USER} -P {PWD} -Q "use {Database};"
```

Attempts to work with sqlalchemy or pyodbc directly didn't work. Error:

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Code:
Attempt with pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=HOST,PORT;'
    r'DATABASE=DATABASE;'
    r'UID=UID;'
    r'PWD=PWD'
    )
```

Attempt with sqlalchemy:

```
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?driver={driver}'.format(
        user=user,
        password=password,
        host=host,
        database=database,
        port=port,
        driver="ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
    )).connect()
```

I can reproduce the error with sqlcmd if I remove the port from the command, so maybe the conn_string I am passing to pyodbc is not in the correct format?

Comment: I am having the same problem but on my Mac machine. Only difference is that I am using OBDC driver 13 instead. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Even i'm  facing the same problem with ODBC driver 13 on redhat. Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @Solaiman late reply here, but the answer below is correct. It ended up being a typo-caused DNS issue for me. It is worth trying the endpoint outside the python code first before debugging this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be DNS related, as you can read [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/412).
Try to use an IP address, instead of the hostname, in the connection string, or check your DNS configuration.

Comment: localhost worked when testing with mssql-cli, but in python I had to use the loopback ip

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this happened when I didn't properly escape passwords that has special characters. This was my solution:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
...
passwd = 'p@ssw0rd!'
...
engine_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{quote(passwd)}@{host}/{name}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

Comment: Saved me a huge amount of hours, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! You saved my life. I've been working for 2 hours and cannot find out why the error happened. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

What does your python code do? Problem might be multiple Connections calls. Dont open the connection in a loop. Or conn.close() at the wrong point. 
Other problem could be a firewall rule issue, check it.

I use pymssql to acces to my sql server. Read the documentation and install pymssql and freetds-dev on your centos system. Maybe u need to edit freetds.conf and add the ip and port of your sql server.