# Unable to set up SQL Server backend using pyodbc for airflow on a Centos 7 server

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, centos7, pyodbc

I'm trying to set up SQL Server backend for airflow. But getting this timeout error, when I do `airflow initdb`:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My connection string in `airflow.cfg` looks like:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx,1433/test_db?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

I installed odbc drivers using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#microsoft-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server

My `odbcinst.ini` file looks like:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

I went through these posts:

[Pyodbc: Login Timeout Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046158/pyodbc-login-timeout-error)

[pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069846/pyodbc-operationalerror-hyt00-uhyt00-unixodbcmicrosoftodbc-driver-1)

["Login timeout expired" error when accessing MS SQL db via sqlalchemy and pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996079/login-timeout-expired-error-when-accessing-ms-sql-db-via-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc)

[Remote connection to MS SQL - Error using pyodbc vs success using SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635008/remote-connection-to-ms-sql-error-using-pyodbc-vs-success-using-sql-server-man)

Most of these solutions are about: using SQL Server IP instead of instance name and appending port with IP. But, I'm trying to connect that way already.

When I'm trying to connect to sql server through python venv using:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
database = 'test_db'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
port = '1433'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Tried above connection string without port as well. Still getting the same time out error.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Should it not be 10.10.10.10:1000? As per one of your links it is `@{host}:{port}`

Comment: The default port for SQL Server is 1433 (see [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15)). Did you configure 1000 yourself?

Comment: 1000 as port was an example. When I try to login to that sql server through management studio. That's how I'm able to connect to it by appending port with ip.

Comment: But, I'm trying to connect to another sql server which has default port as 1433 normally through python code. Still getting login time out error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got fixed by internal request, it was a firewall issue.

Comment: Hey - thanks for the info. To confirm, did you open a firewall rule from Airflow to the SQL Server? Having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I didn't do anything from airflow. DB Admin gave access to linux server from where I was running airflow to access db server..

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to your connection string.

For a start there's a typo in the example you've given a comma before defining your `PORT` variable.... but it looks like there's a different shape to connection strings based on your chosen SQL Server driver. And you look like you are using pymssql format rather than pyodbc despite using the ODBC driver.

From SQLALchemy docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server

```py
# pyodbc
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn')

# pymssql
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')
```

Comment: The problem is using `pyodbc` code only, I'm not able to make a connection to db. I'll come to sqlalchemy string later..

Comment: Boring question number 1: the SQL Server is up and running right?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, this is an active server that you're just using Python to connect to

Comment: It is. I'm able to access it using SQL Server Management console